# Typescript ensure event is given type of event

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a code like this

```
type ScanSheetEvents =
  | { type: "updateStationsList"; stationsList: StationCodeList }
  | { type: "reAskPermissions" };
```

And i want to ensure that some type if of given type of throw and get type inference (something like this)

```
(_, event) => {
          throwIfNotEvent(event, "updateStationsList");

          return event.stationsList;
```

I started to write something like that, but I'm not able to make it work… I want auto-completion on event when type is ensured.

```
function throwIfNotEvent(
  event: ScanSheetEvents,
  eventType: ScanSheetEvents["type"],
): event is …  {
  if (event.type !== eventType) throw Error("Unexpected event" + event.type);
}
```

maybe someone could help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like:

```
function throwIfNotEvent<T extends ScanSheetEvents['type']>(
  event: ScanSheetEvents,
  eventType: T,
): asserts event is ScanSheetEvents & { type: T } {
  if (event.type !== eventType) throw Error("Unexpected event" + event.type);
}
```

This function now has a generic type parameter `T` which is constrained by the union of `type` properties in `ScanSheetEvents`. See [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

The return value is `asserts event is ...` which means that an exception is expected to be thrown if `event` is not of the stated type. See [Assertion Functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).

`ScanSheetEvents & { type: T }` means that the union of all events is filtered down to just the ones that match whatever type was passed as `eventType`. See [Intersection Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)

And now this function will work without complaint:

```
const fn = (event: ScanSheetEvents) => {
    throwIfNotEvent(event, "updateStationsList");
    return event.stationsList; // works
}
```

[See Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=14&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwCWB7AdgYRQEwgGSQGdgoBeKYgJyTQHMBtAXQChnRJYBjeNGACwgRgAUQBuENMEJlmUKAB8oAbyjsIALigAiAK5hsiCHESo0hAsS0BuCgmTpzRYJuP3MOfE6gBfWQuWq4BralBAAgoQA1gAKEJQAtkSEpoRaPlasAGY6aJxuqnyUKADuAJKZAHIoIuKSADwAKlAQAB7AEtjSMNy8AkJiElL0AORqw4wAfAAUfhC1zlw8-II1g4QANLPzDUGaDZsAlJrwhIRxUs3zUESLvSsDktIAZAFqez7KfkiZUFNzgwA6NRQACEpHI-0kO0gBwKRWKUGElCKlCmWgAqmhWpA8hBsJdBmkANQEyRAoIHDK+ZicBwkTJoMi-SELbpLPqrR6w0gTT5yOTAQolcpVTnAP7zdbaPQGdquFIWYBaSl+OShYA6SiMlkA4gmByKmwAeiNUGKKEokUIzG8QA)

Comment: Damn you're good… and so fast! Thanks, mate, it works perfectly, hope to be good as you're in TS someday ;)